# How do I restrict a custom group to edit pages on mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to restrict edit functionality for the group 'test' but unable to do so. Below are the changes I made so far:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['test']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['test']['edit'] = false;
```

Comment: ok, so the group test can still edit, yes? Do you have assigned a user to the group test? Be sure, that "test" is the _only_ group this user has. wgGroupPermissions is cumulative, so you can't revoke a right by setting it to false in one group, if another group (the user belongs to, too) has the right granted. Read https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgGroupPermissions and use https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRevokePermissions for revocation of rights.

Comment: Yes I assigned a user 't1' to the group 'test'. Will the user 't1' by default be member of default group 'user'? If yes then how to keep him only in the new group?

Comment: Ok. Got it by using mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRevokePermissions. Thx Florian.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you create a new group and you want to revoke a permission for this group. [`$wgGroupPermissions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRevokePermissions) isn't made to revoke permissions. Permissions granted via `$wgGroupPermissions` are cumulative, which means, that the permissions of *all* groups a user belongs to, reflects the permissions, the user has. If you set the `edit` permission of a group to false, and another group (e.g. `user`) has the `edit` permissions (set to true), the user (who belongs to both groups) will have the permission to edit. That's (maybe) a bit better explained on the Manual page (see the link above).

To achieve what you want, you need to:

- Remove any other group with the edit permission from the user (that's not a good idea, if you have any other groups with special rights you get a really confusing and complex construct of permission management)
- Use [`$wgRevokePermissions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRevokePermissions) instead, see the example about how to revoke the `edit` permission for a group

Example to achieve what you want:

```
// inherit all rights from the user group
$wgGroupPermissions['test'] = $wgGroupPermissions['user'];
// revoke the edit permission for users in the group test
$wgRevokePermissions['test']['edit'] = true;
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In MediaWiki, all users (including anonymous visitors) automatically belong to the group `*`, and all *registered* users (i.e. not anons) belong to the group `user`.  [By default](https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fcore.git/refs%2Fheads%2FREL1_25/includes%2FDefaultSettings.php#L4516), both of these automatic groups have the `edit` permission set to `true`, so every user can automatically edit pages.

To [restrict editing to only certain users](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_editing_of_all_pages), you first need to remove those automatic edit rights by adding the following lines to your LocalSettings.php:

```php
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
```

Now only users in groups that have the `edit` permission set to `true` can edit pages.  There are no such groups by default, so to let *anyone* edit anything on your wiki, you'll have to add a few more lines to LocalSettings.php.  For example, here's how to let admins (i.e. users in the group `sysop`) edit pages:

```php
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['edit'] = true;
```

---

Alternatively, as already noted by Florian, you could use [`$wgRevokePermissions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRevokePermissions) to remove editing rights from certain users.  For example, here's how to allow all registered users, *except* those in the group `blocked`, to edit:

```php
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;        // anons can't edit
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = true;      // normal users can edit
$wgRevokePermissions['blocked']['edit'] = true;  // "blocked" users cannot
```

(Of course, the built-in [user blocking](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Block_and_unblock) feature in MediaWiki accomplishes this much better.)

---

Another option, if you wish to restrict editing only in certain namespaces, would be to use [`$wgNamespaceProtection`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgNamespaceProtection), which lets you define a custom user right needed to edit pages in certain namespaces.  For example, to allow only users in the custom group `editor` to edit pages in the main namespace, you could use:

```php
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_MAIN] = array( 'edit-main' );
$wgGroupPermissions['editor']['edit-main'] = true;
```